# Rails has_many through singular association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many, has-many-through

This is probably quite simple but I haven't yet been able to wrap my head around the problem.

I have 3 tables... (well more than that) but in this scenario 3 that matter.

Places
Bookings and
Ratings

Places has_many bookings

Each booking has_one rating (because the user only rates once) and belongs_to (a) Place

Ratings belong_to (a) Booking

So even though bookings has only one rating, places has_many ratings through bookings as places has many bookings also

but this doesn't seem to work?  All the rest seem to.

Bookings has place_id and Ratings has a booking_id, and I've been successful with all other has_many through associations... just not the has_one?  Any ideas?  Thanks

addition: if i change Bookings to has_many :ratings it works... but bookings will only ever have one rating per booking... so this doesn't seem like a good thing.

```
Invalid source reflection macro :has_one for has_many :ratings, :through => :bookings.  Use :source to specify the source reflection.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_many :through` doesn't work with `has_one` relations on the join model; see the following Rails tickets for details:

- https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1149
- https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2719-has_many-through-should-work-if-the-join-model-uses-has_one-relationship

If possible, the best solution is probably to modify your relations so that a Booking `belongs_to` a Rating rather than `has_one` Rating.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I just bumped rails up to 2.3.4 from 2.3.2 and now the association seems to work.